# ReactJs error - Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error can anyone please tell me how I can debug this further?

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op.

Can anyone help?

This is my component which is causing the error:

```
var postal = require('postal'),
contactChannel = postal.channel("contact"),
React = require('react');

var ContactSelector = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        selectedContacts:[]
    };
},

handleChange: function(e) {
    var id = e.target.attributes['data-ref'].value;

    if (e.target.checked === true){
        contactChannel.publish({
                    channel: "contact",
                    topic: "selectedContact",
                    data: {
                        id: id
                    }});

    } else{
        contactChannel.publish({
            channel: "contact",
            topic: "deselectedContact",
            data: {
                id: id
            }
        });

    }
},

render: function() {

    var id = this.props.data.id;
    var isSelected = this.props.data.IsSelected;

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox"
                checked={isSelected} data-ref={id}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}

});
module.exports = ContactSelector;
```

The contactChannel is a channel I've setup using postal.js, https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js

```
 contactChannel.subscribe("selectedContact",function (data, envelope) {

        page.setPersonIsSelectedState(data.id, true);

        basketChannel.publish({
            channel: "basket",
            topic: "addPersonToBasket",
            data: {
                personId: data.id
            }
        });
    });
```

I suscribe to the publish in componentDidMount on my parent page:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var page = this;
    this.loadContacts();

    page.subscribeEvents();
},
```

Listeners:

subscribeEvents: function() {

```
    var page = this;

    page.subscribeToChannel(filterChannel, "searchFilterChange", this.listenerForSearchFilterChanged);

    contactChannel.subscribe("pageSizeChanged", this.listenerForSizeChanged);


    page.subscribeToChannel(filterChannel, "genderFilterChange", this.listnerForGenderFilterChange);

    page.subscribeToChannel(filterChannel, "rollModeFilterChange", this.listnerForRollModeFilterChange);

    page.subscribeToChannel(filterChannel, "attendanceModeFilterChange", this.listnerForAttendanceModeFilterChange)

    page.subscribeToChannel(filterChannel, "messageToFilterChange", this.listnerForMessageToFilterChange);

    contactChannel.subscribe("selectAll", function (data) {
        page.loadContacts();
    });


    contactChannel.subscribe("selectedContact",function (data, envelope) {

        page.setPersonIsSelectedState(data.id, true);

        basketChannel.publish({
            channel: "basket",
            topic: "addPersonToBasket",
            data: {
                personId: data.id
            }
        });
    });

    contactChannel.subscribe("selectAll", function (data, envelope) {

        basketChannel.publish({
            channel: "basket",
            topic: "selectAll",
            data: {
                selectAll: data.selectAll
            }
        });

    });

    contactChannel.subscribe("refreshContacts", function (data, envelope) {
        page.loadContacts();

    });
},
```

Comment: what is in contactchannel ? the problem is comign from there

Comment: There is no any `setState` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about using react incorrectly. React is built to be componentized, so you'll want to be doing everything in components.

When you're setting up your app, you'll want to use postal's subscribe inside of each of your components' `getInitialState`. Then, unsubscribe from the postal channels in the `componentWillUnmount` functions.

It seems that the offending code is missing from the snippets in your question, if you post all your code on I could look at it and tell you specifically where you are still "subscribed" to a postal event on a component that is no longer mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Add a ref attribute to your  root div, and check that ref value before calling setState . This will make sure the component is mounted.

render: function() {

```
var id = this.props.data.id;
var isSelected = this.props.data.IsSelected;

return (
    <div ref='some_ref' className="contact-selector">
        <input type="checkbox"
            checked={isSelected} data-ref={id}
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>
);
```

}

then call setState like below

`this.refs.some_ref ? this.setState({yourState:value}): null;`